Criteria for log-absolute-monotonicity
Consider a function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by a power series $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots$, where all $a_i$ are positive.
Is there are any criterion in terms of the coefficients $a_i$ to ensure that $f$ is logarithmically-absolute-monotonic, that is, that  $(\log f)^{(k)}(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1], k \in \mathbb N$?
For example, it would seem that if the $a_i$ values grow faster than the exponential function (which has $a_i = 1/i!$) this should work.
I am specifically interested in a function related to the incomplete Beta function, with
$$
a_i = \frac{ \Gamma(\alpha+i) }{i! (\beta+i) }
$$
for $\alpha, \beta \in (0,1)$.
It seems that the coefficients here are indeed fast-growing, and computer experiments indicate that indeed this function is logarithmically-absolute-monotonic.

@Iosef: thank you, i fixed it

If $\alpha=1, \beta=0$, then (after omitting $a_0$), $\log(f)=\log\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$, which is not even convex for small values of $x$.

@Diffusion -- at $\beta = 0$ it indeed blows up. I think that the statement still holds for $\beta > 0$ strictly. I modified the problem to avoid this edge case.

I would try to find a product representation $f(x)=e^{h(x)} \prod (1-c_ix)^{-1}$ for a polynomial $h$ and $c_i\in (0,1)$
